# How to get query string right before a slash

Tags: asp.net-mvc, request, http-request

There are weird occasions where our website is accessed with the following url:

```
http://website.com/search/?category=test&keyword=test
```

As you can see there is a weird slash sitting in front of the question mark and this fools my asp.net mvc app to think there is no query string. Now the client wants the slash removed (SEO issues),  hence redirecting the user to

```
http://website.com/search?category=test&keyword=test
```

Apparently `Request.Url.Query` returns empty string :( what is the best way to correctly parse the query string if theres a slash before it in asp.net mvc?

Comment: Can your search category and keyword be null or empty string? Usually this problem can be solved by declaring custom `MapRoute` and use `BeginRouteForm` on view.

Comment: I just tried this, and this.Request.Url.Query returned me the query string as expected.